# LINQ to Entities- Time difference in Hours coming incorrect

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities, aggregate

I have a table named "Videos" in my Sql Server database. I am using LINQ to Entities to access data from that database from a C# application.
"Videos" table includes two columns named "RecordingStarted" and "RecordingEnded", that would simply tell us the starting and ending datetime of recorded video. Each Video has a unique ID and is recorded against a Unit (by unit here I mean, example a cell phone).

"Videos" table sample data is like following:

```
UnitID  VideoID        RecordingStarted            RecordingEnded
====================================================================
Unit-1  vid1           2012/1/1 14:30:00           2012/1/1 15:45:10
Unit-1  vid2           2012/2/1 12:30:00           2012/1/1 12:50:00
Unit-2  vid3           2012/3/1 14:30:00           2012/3/1 15:45:10
Unit-2  vid4           2012/4/1 12:30:00           2012/4/1 12:40:00
```

Using LINQ to Entities I want to calculate aggregate data for a report, and for every unit like the total number of video hours recorded by each unit.

Output should be like following:

```
UnitID     Total Video Hours
================================================
Unit-1      0.58611
Unit-2      0.41944
```

I have created following LINQ to entities query but it is not giving me correct results. (I guess hours are rounded to 0 on division by 3600)

```
IQueryable<dynamic> qry = myContext.Videos
.GroupBy(v => new { v.UnitID })
.Select(g => new
{
    g.Key.UnitID,
    TotalVideoHours = g.Sum(c => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", c.RecordingStarted, c.RecordingEnded)/3600)
});

var result = qry.ToList();
```

Also: I need the hours rounded to 2 digits, (right from Sql Server and not using an in-memory operation later on).

How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is dividing by 3600, which truncates the fractional hours you get when dividing by 3600: you need to use 3600.0 instead. We can then wrap with a deliberate truncation using EntityFunctions.Truncate to get the nice 2 digit format. Also not sure why you need an `IQueryable<dynamic>` here.

```
var qry = s.Videos
.GroupBy(v => new { v.Name })
.Select(g => new
{
    g.Key.Name,
    TotalVideoHours = EntityFunctions.Truncate(g.Sum(c => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", c.RecordingStarted, c.RecordingEnded) / 3600.0), 2)
});
```

Comment: 3600.00. Ignored such a simple thing :)
Regarding use of "dynamic", this is an extra thing that I later used in my app for some other scenario. That's not needed here in fact. A "var" can suffice here.